# How to add values of a dictionary together python with a function

Tags: python, dictionary

```
import csv

def statistics():
    statistics2 = {}
    with open("BLS_private.csv") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            statistics2 = row

    return statistics2


statistics()
```

Dicionary sample data:

```
['2005', '110718', '110949', '111094', '111440', '111583', '111844', '112124', '112311', '112395', '112491', '112795', '112935']
['2006', '113250', '113535', '113793', '113958', '113965', '114045', '114203', '114348', '114434', '114439', '114628', '114794']
```

How would I go about adding all of the values together in a row except for the first value in a dictionary?

The first value is always the year; like in the sample data i have 2005 and 2006. I don't need to add the year.

Then I want to add together all of the values after that in the row. How would I do that?

(I also have a lot of years)

Comment: Is the dictionary key the first element? ie. the year?

Comment: can you add how should be the end result?

Comment: yes it is aggragoth.

Comment: the end result should look like : [ '2005' , '443000']   (the 443000 is the sum of the other numbers in the dictionary row)

Comment: Are  you sure, 444300 is the sum of the other values?  It seems to be much more. The quick and dirty way will be `sum(a[1:])` (where a is one of your lists which represent a row), but you will need to convert the values to an int first. Also a few other things: 1) you reference a dictionary multiple times in your post, but don't provide a dictionary, just a few lists. 2) I don't know what else you'll be doing with this, but you may find an external package (like Pandas) will greatly assist with this type of data processing

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow :)

You can achieve this by utilizing list.pop(index) to grab the first item in the list as the key, and list comprehension to calculate the sums of the remaining values.

```
    ## Assign variable for dictionary ##
    dictionary = {}

    ## Data assuming it is formatted as lists within a list ##

    data = [['2005', '110718', '110949', '111094', '111440', '111583', '111844', '112124', '112311', '112395', '112491', '112795', '112935'],
    ['2006', '113250', '113535', '113793', '113958', '113965', '114045', '114203', '114348', '114434', '114439', '114628', '114794']]

    ## Iterate over all lists within your data list
    for i in data:

        ## Utilize list.pop(index) to grab and remove the first item in the list (Index 0)
        key = i.pop(0)

        ## Create a key in the dictonary using the value we popped off the list
        ## Sum all values left in the list as an integer if it is a digit
        dictionary[key] = sum([int(v) for v in i if v.isdigit()])

    ## Result

    dictionary
    {'2005': 1342679, '2006': 1369392}
```